# Converting Open Office (odt) files to Latex

Tags: linux, openoffice, latex, openoffice-writer, libreoffice

How do you convert Open Office (ODT) documents to tex files?
I have made a **report using libre office**. Now I wish to **continue editing** the document **using lyx (latex front end)**.  So the ODT file needs to be saved as some .tex file.

I don't see an option to do this in File menu (export/save as). So is there any other plugin to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenOffice used to have a LaTeX export functionality, which was later removed, I guess. Nevertheless, there is a LaTeX writer:

```
sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-writer2latex writer2latex
```

Or, if your distribution uses LibreOffice, use `libreoffice-writer2latex` instead of the above.

Just confirm all messages with `y`. After installing, you can use it with `w2l`

```
w2l your-document.odt
```

which will create a `.tex` file with the same name. The formatting is pretty basic, but I think it gets the job done.

If you wish to edit it in Lyx after that, just concatenate the commands, something like that:

```
w2l your-document.odt && /usr/bin/env lyx your-document.tex &
```

<sub>I tested the conversion on Ubuntu 11.04 with the default LibreOffice installation</sub>

Comment: The package is now called libreoffice-writer2latex, at least in fedora.

Comment: On Debian Squeeze, the package seems to be called `writer2latex`. At least, that package provides a `w2l` that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Libreoffice has a writer2latex extension that you can load simply by double-clicking on the .oxt file or by getting the package from apt ( I assume also yum )

Link to extension: `http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/index14.html`

Once you install the extension, you can use File->Export to .tex.

**But:**

- I was unable to get Libreoffice 4.0x to run the extension against a
  complex document.
- LO 3.4.4 ran the extension just fine, but lost almost all formatting,
  lost all tables and pictures.

**Bottom Line:**

I gave up. You'd be better off just exporting to text, and starting over. It appears to me as a complete NOOB to Lyx and Latex, that many document settings don't have an equivalent, and simply can't be translated. However I'd be delighted to be shown that I am wrong.